# Artifactory cleaning up temp folder

Tags: artifactory

I have a question related to Artifactory Jfrog..
Is it safe to delete files in /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/temp folder?

Taking up a lot of spaces

Thank you

Comment: I don't have a `temp` folder in this location on my instance. What kind of files are in there? When was the last change made to this folder? It may be something unrelated that somebody created manually at some point.

Comment: @DarthFennec all files are of these rpm.entry1191252755048999627xml type

Comment: I'm not familiar with RPM enough to know what that is ... how old is the most recently changed file, if you can tell? If they're all really old then they probably aren't being used by anything.

Comment: They are couple month old only..

Comment: That seems pretty old to me, I feel like if Artifactory was generating these it would do so much more frequently. Were they all created at the same time a couple months ago, or at consistent intervals? In the former case, someone probably created those files one day and just left them there, for a reason or by accident. I can't say whether they're important to that person, but I'm fairly convinced that Artifactory wouldn't care if they went missing, at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The temp folder is generally safe to delete as Artifactory uses it as a staging area for various indices it creates and for other generated files.

take care with a folder called `artifactory-uploads` if its present - that is the staging area for ui-originated uploads so you might end up deleting a file that represents an upload in progress, so only delete old files from that location.